# Looking for clarification on overall goal of the following Loop Condition

Tags: python, loops

I have been given the following instructions!

> get_first_name():
>
> 1. set i equal to zero
> 2. Loop while i is less than the length of name and the i-th character i not a space
> 3. increase i by 1
> 4. Return the part of name up to but not including the i-th character to the caller

I am hoping someone could clarify to me the overall goal and point of these instructions.

```
def get_first_name():
    name = raw_input("Please enter your Forename: ")
    i = 0
    while i < len(name):
        i = i + 1
        return name
```

Comment: Your code is most likely bad indented. The `return` statement is called after the first loop.

Comment: does not seem to make a difference, even when i indent the return to the def line it still exits the loop when nothing is typed in.

Comment: Of course it skips (not exit : skips) the loop if `name` is an empty string... What did you expect ? Did you ever asked yourself what was the length of an empty string ?

Comment: yes i did and i completely agree, I am just asking if the point of the script is to make a username consisting of first name and last name initial, wouldn't it be better to ensure at least 1 string character to use for the first name.

Comment: I'm quite curious, what was the code that you were expecting? If you say that you should not bother with such a condition, how would you write the loop? You can edit your question saying e.g. "I was expecting something like this" and put your code.

Answer (score 1):

> i was wondering why bother having a loop condition of 0

The loop condition is `i < len(name)`, not `0`.

> as it will always break the loop no matter what.

If it was `while 0:` (which is what 'a loop condition of 0' would be), then it wouldn't break the loop at all, it would just not even enter the loop's body.

> isnt the point of the loop to make the person enter at least one character to be used for the name.

Did you bother reading the assignment ?

> Loop while i is less than the length of name **and the i-th character i not a space** 
>   (...)
>   Return the part of name up to but not including the i-th character

Actually the point is to find the position of the first space in the string and return the part of the string preceding this position.

Comment: @DarrenMacis this is a **while** loop - it executes as long as the condition is true. If `i == 0` and `len(name) > 0`, then `i < len(name)` is true, obviously. And I admit I may be spoiled by all those years spent writing code but from the instructions it seems quite clear *to me* that "the point of the loop" is to find the position of the first white space in the string, not to "make the person enter at least one character" (FWIW there's not even a mention of user input in the instructions you posted - as far as I'm concerned I'd write this function as taking "name" as argument).

Answer (score 0):

If your trying to get the number of letters of the name then your code is wrong as you need to return `i`. And also the indentation is wrong of the return statement.Also you need to start from 0 or else you will get a value short of the names.

```
def get_first_name():
    name = raw_input("Please enter your Forename: ")
    i = 0
    while i < len(name):
        i = i + 1
    return i

print get_first_name()
```